# Drop-Down links are not showing In HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I Have an HTML table inside which  i am creating drop-down in one column which will have two links to go forward or to show something, i have successfully created the drop-down button but the drop-down links are not showing.

please refer to the snippet

```js
var currentlyClickedCode = "";
 $(document).ready(function (){
   
    $dropdown = $("#contextMenu");
       $(".actionButton").click(function() {
         //move dropdown menu
         $(this).after($dropdown);
         //update links 
         $(this).dropdown();

         currentlyClickedCode = $(this).attr("data-place");
         console.log(currentlyClickedCode)
         
       });
  var tableData=[
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C001",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Beverages",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 18
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C002",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Shakes",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 80
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C003",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Juices",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 70
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C004",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Soups",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 55
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C005",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Cookies",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 46
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C006",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Buns",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 21
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C007",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Breads",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 40
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C008",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Rusks",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 52
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C009",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Biscuits",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 38
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C010",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Puff",
                   "QUANTITY": "4.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 132
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C011",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Savouries",
                   "QUANTITY": "0.1000",
                   "AMOUNT": 29
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C012",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Cake",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 46
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C014",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "IceCream",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 70
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C019",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Curry",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 180
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C021",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Starter",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 165
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C022",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Roti",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 60
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C023",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Chawal",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 185
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C024",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Dessert",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 66
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C026",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Soup",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 100
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C027",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Salad",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 50
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C028",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Set Menu",
                   "QUANTITY": "3.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 1290
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C029",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Pastry",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 80
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C030",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Packed Meals",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 25
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C031",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Packaging",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 5
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C034",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Bhath",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 68
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C036",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Snacks",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 10
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C037",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Breakfast",
                   "QUANTITY": "5.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 119
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C038",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Evening Snacks",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 70
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C040",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Sandwich",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 75
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C042",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Burger",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 75
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C043",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Meals",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 220
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C044",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Curd",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 12
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C048",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Combo",
                   "QUANTITY": "2.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 180
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C051",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Silver Thali",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 450
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C052",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Sweets",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 115
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C054",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Instant Mixes",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 66
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C055",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "RTE",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 228
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C057",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Spices",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 40
                 },
                 {
                   "CATEGORY CODE": "C061",
                   "CATEGORY NAME": "Fast Food",
                   "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
                   "AMOUNT": 15
                 }
               ]
      
    function addTable(tableData) {
       var col = Object.keys(tableData[0]); 
         
       var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
       var num = col.splice(0, countNum); 
       col = col.concat(num); 
       
       var table = document.createElement("table");

       // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

       var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.


         for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
           var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
           th.innerHTML = col[i];
                
           tr.appendChild(th);
       }

       // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
       for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {

           tr = table.insertRow(-1);

           for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
               var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                var tabledata = tableData[i][col[j]];
         if(tabledata && !isNaN(tabledata)){
           tabledata = parseInt(tabledata).toLocaleString('en-in')
         }
         if( tableData[i]['CATEGORY CODE'] === tableData[i][col[j]]){
             a = document.createElement("a");
             tabCell.classList.add("dropdown");
             a.classList.add("btn");
             a.classList.add("btn-default");
             a.classList.add("actionButton");
             /*  a.classList.add("text-center"); */
             /*  a.setAttribute("data-place", outlet);
             a.setAttribute("data-plac", element); */
             a.setAttribute("data-toggle", "dropdown");
             a.setAttribute("data-place", tableData[i]['CATEGORY CODE']); //this to print on console which drop-down button is clicked.
             a.innerHTML = tabledata;
             tabCell.appendChild(a);
         } else {
             span = document.createElement("span");
             span.innerHTML = tabledata;
             tabCell.appendChild(span)
         } 

            
         
         
         
         
         
         
         
 
                   if (j > 1)
                    {
                  
                   tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
                    }
           }
       }

       // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
       var divContainer = document.getElementById("table1");
       divContainer.innerHTML = "";
       divContainer.appendChild(table);
       table.classList.add("table");
        table.classList.add("table-striped");
        table.classList.add("table-bordered");
 
       }
  addTable(tableData)
   
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
     <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    ></script>
<div id="table1"> 

</div>
   <ul id="contextMenu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="test1.jsp" class="link1">BillSummary</a></li>
        <li><a href="test.jsp" class="link2">Item Summary</a></li>
      
    </ul>
```

in my above snippet code is running successfully  and creating the dropdown button ,but not showing the links.

What i am trying to achieve is

1. To show the drop-down link when click on drop-down button.
2. Print on console which drop-down button is clicked

i am applying the right approach but don't know where it is going wrong.
so please guide me,any kind of help or guidance will be helpful.

my code is throwing error this `"TypeError: $(...).dropdown is not a function`

[please check this link](https://jsbin.com/revujohogu/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't attach `.click()` event listener to dynamically generated elements.
You have to use `.on()` instead:

```
$(document).on("click",".actionButton",function() {
   ... code here ... 
}
```

```js
var currentlyClickedCode = "";
$(document).ready(function() {

  $dropdown = $("#contextMenu");
  $(document).on("click",".actionButton",function() {
    //move dropdown menu
    $(this).after($dropdown);
    //update links 
    $(this).dropdown();

    currentlyClickedCode = $(this).attr("data-place");
    console.log(currentlyClickedCode);

  });
  var tableData = [{
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C001",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Beverages",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 18
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C002",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Shakes",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 80
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C003",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Juices",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 70
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C004",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Soups",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 55
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C005",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Cookies",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 46
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C006",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Buns",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 21
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C007",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Breads",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 40
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C008",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Rusks",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 52
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C009",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Biscuits",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 38
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C010",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Puff",
      "QUANTITY": "4.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 132
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C011",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Savouries",
      "QUANTITY": "0.1000",
      "AMOUNT": 29
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C012",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Cake",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 46
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C014",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "IceCream",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 70
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C019",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Curry",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 180
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C021",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Starter",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 165
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C022",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Roti",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 60
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C023",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Chawal",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 185
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C024",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Dessert",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 66
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C026",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Soup",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 100
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C027",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Salad",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 50
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C028",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Set Menu",
      "QUANTITY": "3.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 1290
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C029",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Pastry",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 80
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C030",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Packed Meals",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 25
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C031",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Packaging",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 5
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C034",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Bhath",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 68
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C036",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Snacks",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 10
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C037",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Breakfast",
      "QUANTITY": "5.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 119
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C038",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Evening Snacks",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 70
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C040",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Sandwich",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 75
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C042",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Burger",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 75
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C043",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Meals",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 220
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C044",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Curd",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 12
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C048",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Combo",
      "QUANTITY": "2.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 180
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C051",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Silver Thali",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 450
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C052",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Sweets",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 115
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C054",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Instant Mixes",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 66
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C055",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "RTE",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 228
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C057",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Spices",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 40
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C061",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Fast Food",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 15
    }
  ]

  function addTable(tableData) {
    var col = Object.keys(tableData[0]);

    var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
    var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
    col = col.concat(num);

    var table = document.createElement("table");

    // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

    var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.


    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
      var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
      th.innerHTML = col[i];

      tr.appendChild(th);
    }

    // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
    for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {

      tr = table.insertRow(-1);

      for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
        var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
        var tabledata = tableData[i][col[j]];
        if (tabledata && !isNaN(tabledata)) {
          tabledata = parseInt(tabledata).toLocaleString('en-in')
        }
        if (tableData[i]['CATEGORY CODE'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          a = document.createElement("a");
          tabCell.classList.add("dropdown");
          a.classList.add("btn");
          a.classList.add("btn-default");
          a.classList.add("actionButton");
          /*  a.classList.add("text-center"); */
          /*  a.setAttribute("data-place", outlet);
          a.setAttribute("data-plac", element); */
          a.setAttribute("data-toggle", "dropdown");
          a.setAttribute("data-place", tableData[i]['CATEGORY CODE']); //this to print on console which drop-down button is clicked.
          a.innerHTML = tabledata;
          tabCell.appendChild(a);
        } else {
          span = document.createElement("span");
          span.innerHTML = tabledata;
          tabCell.appendChild(span)
        }










        if (j > 1) {

          tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
        }
      }
    }

    // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("table1");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);
    table.classList.add("table");
    table.classList.add("table-striped");
    table.classList.add("table-bordered");

  }
  addTable(tableData)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="table1">

</div>
<ul id="contextMenu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li><a href="test1.jsp" class="link1">BillSummary</a></li>
  <li><a href="test.jsp" class="link2">Item Summary</a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: @viveksingh yes. Indeed. That's the only change you need to make